# PHP Mail Form Recipients Receiving Multiple Copies

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, email

I have a PHP mail form that I've set up which utilizes AJAX & jQuery to validate and submit the form. Everything seems to work fine, but for whatever reason my client (the website owner) receives multiple copies of each mail send. The number of copies varies from 1 to 10 copies of each message, with no specific pattern.

In all the tests I've done I personally only receive 1 copy of the message at my business email address, and at another gmail account as well. Yet the client, whose domain registrar hosts their email accounts, receives anywhere up to 10 copies at once.

We are hosting the website, and therefor our server is processing the form each time a message is sent. I've checked our server mail logs and can confirm that it's only being sent out once.

This is driving me nuts. We're not spending hours trying to figure this out and losing money with every minute wasted on this issue.

I'll provide you with my code and the live website. Hopefully someone can help me out!!

---

First of all, here is the website where you can see the form in action: http://www.energywisesolutions.ca/

You can click any 'Book a Home Evaluation' link/button to see the form slide open.

---

This is the script I'm using for form validation: http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/

---

Here is my form validation check, and then form send script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

/* ASSESSMENT FORM
----------------------------------------------------------------*/

// Form Validation
$("#contact-form .send").click(function(){
    $("#contact-form").validationEngine('attach', {
        onValidationComplete: function(form, status){
            if(status==true){
                $("#contact-form .send").clone().insertAfter($(this)).attr("disabled","true");
            $("#contact-form .send").hide();
                _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/online-thankyou']);
                $.post('/themes/energywise/mail-form/process.php', $("#contact-form").serialize(), function(data) {
                    // Add Thank You Message
                    $('#thank-you-message').html(data);
                    // Create IFRAME to page with Adwords Tracking Script
                    function ppcconversion() {
                        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                        iframe.style.width = '0px';
                        iframe.style.height = '0px';
                        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
                        iframe.src = 'http://www.energywisesolutions.ca/themes/energywise/mail-form/conversion-script.php';
                    };
                    ppcconversion();

                });
            }
        }
    });
});

});
```

And here is my form process script:

```
$toAdmin='info@energywisesolutions.ca';
$fromAdmin='info@energywisesolutions.ca';
$toVisitor=stripslashes($_POST['email']);

$name=stripslashes($_POST['full_name']);
$city=stripslashes($_POST['city']);
$phone=stripslashes($_POST['phone']);
$comments=stripslashes($_POST['comments']);

/* TO ADMIN */
$headersToAdmin = "From: " .$toVisitor. "\r\n";
$headersToAdmin .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

$subjectToAdmin='Energywise Website Lead - Home Assessment Form';

$messageToAdmin = '<html><body>';
$messageToAdmin .= '<img src="http://www.energywisesolutions.ca/energy-rebates/form1.jpg" alt="Home Assessment Form" />';
$messageToAdmin .= '<p>A website visitor has filled out thea Home Assessment Form. Here is their information and the comments they provided:</p>';
$messageToAdmin .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
$messageToAdmin .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Sent From:</strong> </td><td>ENERGYWISE WEBSITE</td></tr>";
$messageToAdmin .= "<tr><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>" .$name. "</td></tr>";
$messageToAdmin .= "<tr><td><strong>City:</strong> </td><td>" .$city. "</td></tr>";
$messageToAdmin .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" .$toVisitor. "</td></tr>";
$messageToAdmin .= "<tr><td><strong>Phone:</strong> </td><td>" .$phone. "</td></tr>";
$messageToAdmin .= "<tr><td><strong>Comments:</strong> </td><td>" .$comments. "</td></tr>";
$messageToAdmin .= "</table>";
$messageToAdmin .= "</body></html>";


/* TO VISITOR */
$headersToVisitor = "From: " .$fromAdmin. "\r\n";
$headersToVisitor .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

$subjectToVisitor='Thank you for Contacting Energywise Solutions';

$messageToVisitor = '<html><body>';
$messageToVisitor .= '<img src="http://www.energywisesolutions.ca/energy-rebates/form1.jpg" alt="Home Assessment Form" />';
$messageToVisitor .= '<p>Hello,</p> 
                            <p>Thank you for contacting Energywise Solutions. We have received your message and will get in touch with you shortly.</p> 
                            <p>Your information has been attached below:</p>';
$messageToVisitor .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
$messageToVisitor .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>" .$name. "</td></tr>";
$messageToVisitor .= "<tr><td><strong>City:</strong> </td><td>" .$city. "</td></tr>";
$messageToVisitor .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" .$toVisitor. "</td></tr>";
$messageToVisitor .= "<tr><td><strong>Phone:</strong> </td><td>" .$phone. "</td></tr>";
$messageToVisitor .= "<tr><td><strong>Comments:</strong> </td><td>" .$comments. "</td></tr>";
$messageToVisitor .= "</table>";
$messageToVisitor .= "</body></html>";


mail($toAdmin, $subjectToAdmin, $messageToAdmin, $headersToAdmin);
mail($toVisitor, $subjectToVisitor, $messageToVisitor, $headersToVisitor);

print "<h3><strong>Thank you for contacting us.</strong> We will get back to you as soon as possible.</h3> 
<p>We have received your message and will get in touch with you shortly. If you have any immediate questions please feel free to give us a call. You can find the appropriate contact information for your region on our <a href='/locations/'>locations</a> page.</p>";
```

Let me know if there's anything else you need to help me solve this issue. It's driving my clients and myself crazy.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If this is true: _"I've checked our server mail logs and can confirm that it's only being sent out once."_ (and it isn't addressed to multiple people), the problem _cannot be_ on your side. It follows that their mailserver is doing something weird. Do check what is in `$toVisitor` **very** carefully though, `stripslashes` isn't enough, use `filter_var`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Wrikken. I've implemented `filter_var`, instead of `stripslashes`. I don't think it's helped with the issue, but I appreciate the input.I may have to check my mail logs again. Since adding my email address as the admin, I've now also received multiple copies in my inbox. So perhaps it's not specific to their mail server.

Comment: No problem, and I doubt we can help you. Your logs are probably right, and the problem is their side... A _very_ small chance on a misinterpretation of return code from their side (your mail server thinks it's failed and automatically re-queues it for later, their mail server considers it a success), so you might want to try to talk direct SMTP to their server as a test to rule that out.

Comment: Interesting... Could you explain how I could test that out?

Sorry, I'm relatively new to mail handlers and not the most experienced PHP coder.

Comment: Look at the exact response code you get on delivert in your mta's logs. First of all: look for more delivery attempts, if its more then one, it's suspect. Start a [manual SMTP session](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/PERL/node175.html) with telnet or netcat, and enter the exact same mail as you think you are sending. Inquire whether they got it only one or several times then, and compare the status code. If that still does not yield any results, and your are (1) very sure it is indeed only once in the logs and (2) you are addressing only 1 email address, get the sysadmin of the receiver involved.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried binding to the form's onsubmit event instead of the button?

```
$('yourformselector').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // The rest of your validation script
});
```

Comment: Hmm, this seemed to break the script. Not sure what the problem is but it wouldn't send when I tried this.

Answer (score 0):

Try not attaching the `$("#contact-form").validationEngine('attach', {...});` call to the click event of the send button (i.e., call it directly within `$(document).ready(...);`).

It looks like the call to `validationEngine('attach', {...})` is attaching a handler to the form's `submit` event, so this handler is attached once for each time the user clicks the send button.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how I would implement your suggestion. I guess I just don't fully understand. Could you give me an example of how to call it direction within the `$(document).ready(...);)` ?

Comment: Delete this line: `$("#contact-form .send").click(function(){` 
and the second-to-last set of closing brackets that correspond to it `});`

Answer (score 0):

Try switching your form processing script to something like this, your problem is that every time you have $messageToVisito I think an email sends so concatenating your script would help and make it cleaner.

```
$to = 'email@test.com';
$subject = 'Test';
$body = '<html><body>';
// concatenated message
'</html></body>';
$headers = '';
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```